# Some keys keep getting randomnly ignored when typing on my laptop keyboard

Tags: kernel, arch-linux, keyboard

Currently, I have Arch Linux 64-bit installed on the Razer Blade Pro laptop. The only problem I have is that some keystrokes get randomly ignored when typing at normal-fast speed (above 5 keys/sec becomes a problem).

This does not occur when typing slow, and never occurs in windows. Is this a problem with the hid-usb controller and Razer laptop antighosting keyboard?

We tried solving the problem by [following some directions from a forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=161634) which mentioned recompiling the kernel with a modified "drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-core.c" file, hardcoding "interval = 1; at line 1134".

But we did not reach a solution.

My internal devices are:

```
[cristobal@orion ~]$ lsusb -vv -d 1532:

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:0116 Razer USA, Ltd 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:

  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1532 Razer USA, Ltd
  idProduct          0x0116 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          123
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      75
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         0 (Defined at Interface level)
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     159
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      71
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    240 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

What could be the cause of this problem? Directions on where to start looking would be appreciated.

Comment: I remember something I built into a program (DOS, 25 years ago): I added a checksum for the `About` screen, and when you modified that screen, for each day of the month a key was not working (like 1=a 2=b etc). Is this the similar behaviour? Could it be my old program by any chance ( 9750 terminal emulator)?

Comment: I think it is not the same. This is random, like if the hid-usb controller could not catch up with the keyboard typing speed

Comment: Hmm 5x60=300wpm. My solution, type slower. The fastest speed ever recorded on a AlphaNumeric keyboard is only 216wpm. Are you using an antighosting stenograph or something?

Comment: @krowe assume we write in bursts (i was measuring the speed of a burst) so in the end my average speed is much lower than 300wpm. Also i might have exgerated on the 5 value (maybe it is 3 or 4). Anyways, back to the point, the whole idea is that in the end, the speed at which the keyboard does work is in the limit of what is unacceptable. I hope this clears that aspect. The keyboard is antighosting, no stenograph. In case it was not explicit, this is the laptop's keyboard. An external usb keyboard works perfect.

Comment: @labotsirc does this happen both on Xorg and any virtual terminal?

Comment: @Alex yes on both

Comment: maybe this is related http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-input/msg25918.html , in particular this step hit my attention `when the trackpad interface (0) is set to the USB alternate setting of 1: any pretense of being HID inputs for keyboard OR mouse is completely dropped`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried modifying the **"Key repeat delay and rate"** settings? Section 4.2.1 of [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg) says to

- Use `xset r rate delay rate` to change them, then use [xinitrc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc) to make it permanent. Values 170 and 30 respectively are a good start point.
- Then use `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` to view your keyboard settings.

Also, do you have any other Linux distrox installed on the laptop?

If not, perhaps you could try booting from a USB image (Puppy, Mint, etc). If the problem persists, then perhaps you're having more general Linux hardware compatibility issues.

If it doesn't, then your issue is specific to your Arch distro. Make sure you try updating drivers, and perhaps rolling them back as well.

Comment: seems interesting, let me check and will post back. I have not tested other distro, but i have read from other users with ubuntu having the same issue. I will also try to boot Mint to make sure the problem persists.

Comment: Changed the repeat values (tested many values, including the ones you mentioned) but the problem persists.

Comment: This solved it for me. However, I ended up disabling "repeat keys" in universal access / keyboard settings, because I didn't feel like messing with the key repeat delay values.