# On a single application, some key presses are ignored, how to fix it without restarting the application?

Tags: keyboard, swap, synchronization, freeze

Why some key presses are ignored on a single application after my system freezes because of swapping?
and how to fix it without restarting the application?

After it begins, the problem seems to happen every 3 seconds. The same key will be accepted and once every 3s will be ignored.

It just happened with Yakuake (that I use all the time), but happened with other applications in the past too.

And it also happens with some Wine applications, but in this case it is worse, most of keyboard keys are ignored permanently, or remain in a pressed state where the app becomes unusable requiring imediate restart.

As usual, an application restart fix  the problem. I wonder if I could just SIGSTOP the application, fix it somewhere else and SIGCONT it.

My keyboard is USB. I tested connecting to other USB port, but the problem proved to be application related, as it perfectly worked with other applications.

**What it is not:**
- My computer is a desktop, so [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311836/usb-keyboard-is-ignoring-key-presses-in-some-very-frustrating-pattern) is a similar problem but unrelated hardware context.
- [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89181/some-keys-keep-getting-randomnly-ignored-when-typing-on-my-laptop-keyboard) seems a hardware problem affecting all applications.

Also, is there some underlying thing that could be related to this problem causing some kind of synchronism problem?

Comment: Try running yakuake from another xterm window (i know it sounds ridiculous), but with that, you will see some logs when the applications crashes on the xterm window, this logs can help you to fix your app. I cant emulate this problem here, you say is not a hardware problem, but i am not sure about that, some programs are more fragile than others, and hardware bugs can cause different behaviors for each application you run. For example, if the programmer is experienced or know about your hardware, they will workaround the hardware bug.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini mmm... I will try that on next time, btw the app usually does not crash, it just starts having problems with keyboard input (usually the mouse remains fine as I remember)

Comment: Because it is probably crashing partially (in that case the keyboard input), i hope it is showing some message about the problem.